# HTML5 and CSS3 Tutorials

Tags: html, css

Anyone know of any good HTML5 and CSS3 tutorials?

Comment: Hackr.io is a great place to find best online programming tutorials submitted and voted by programming community. Here are links for HTML5: https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-html-5 and CSS3: https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-css

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure..

1. Google - has plenty of good tutorials
2. [net.tutsplus.com](http://net.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/html-css-techniques/) HTML/CSS category - has also plenty of articles according to HTML/CSS (newer articles are about newer technologies ... HTML5 & CSS3)

Answer (score 9):

[Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com) has some of the best tutorials in my opinion - the [W3C.org](http://www.w3.org/) website has some decent tutorials as well.

Answer (score 6):

For me, [Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/. Remember to check the features that you'll use in http://caniuse.com/ in order to know if your audience will be able to run your webapp. The good news is that IE users can use chrome frame, which [recently launched the non-admin installation in the stable channel](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/08/non-admin-chrome-frame-reaches-stable.html).

Also, a time-saving resource is [html5 boiler template](http://html5boilerplate.com/).

Bonus track: [Periodic Table of HTML5 Elements](http://joshduck.com/periodic-table.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been looking for Dive into html5. I saw it few months ago but I forgot the name to search for! Thanks to you. Stackoverflow community rocks.

Comment: Glad to know that I have helped to somebody. BTW, another nice resource http://movethewebforward.org/

Comment: Thanks heaps for introducing me to: movethewebforward.org
It is indeed a cool learning resource.

Answer (score 4):

1. http://css3please.com/ useful css3 snippets that are working crossbrowser
2. http://html5doctor.com/ has some nice html5 articles

Answer (score 4):

**CSS3 -** Tutorials

- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/tag/css3/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/css3-mastery/

**CSS3 -** Reference

- http://w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp

**HTML5** - Tutorials

- http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/html5-and-you/
- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/tag/html5/

**HTML5 -** Reference

- http://w3schools.com/html5/default.asp

If you prefer book over online tutorials i would highly recommend you 'The Book on CSS3' for  css3. http://amzn.to/t8Twzk

Better way for finding new CSS3 HTML5 articles/tutorials is twitter search #HTML5 #CSS3.

Try searching CSS3, HTML5 in www.reddit.com

of course - Google as well!

Answer (score 1):

Apple has some demos with sample code for HTML5 and CSS3 in the [Safari Technology Demos](http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/) section that might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

The best that I have found. Start with tut 1 and do them all.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mp0f0zTPLec&feature=related

Answer (score 1):

**CSS3**

If you're already familiar with CSS2, you may also find this video interesting .

[The CSS3 of Tomorrow by Peter Gasston](http://vimeo.com/22863098)

Answer (score 1):

A valuable source for css related know-how is: http://www.css-tricks.com

Answer (score 0):

I have some tutorials over here http://www.ubelly.com/html5

Answer (score 0):

for CSS3 check http://www.codrops.com, for html5 check http://www.html5doctor.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, get this book: "HTML5 & CSS3 for the Real World" from sitepoint.

Answer (score 0):

w3-video.com with over 400 video demonstrations on HTML5

http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/index.php

Answer (score -1):

http://css.dzone.com/articles/50-best-html5-tutorials-2011
and for basic and quick learn w3schools.com is best one